# Как реализовать обмен данными между модулем Sim5360e и устройством через UART2?

Tags: lua, uart

Реализую обмен данными между модулем Sim5360e и устройством через `UART2`. Пишу на `Lua`, `АТ`-команд для отправки/получения информации через `UART2` не нашел - поэтому использую внутренние функции `devio`.

```
sio.send("AT+CSCLK=0\r\n")
sio.send("AT+CGFUNC=21,1\r\n")
sio.send("AT+IPR2=9600\r\n")

local msg,count=getHex(str)
local unswer
devio.open(3)
devio.write(3,msg,count)
unswer=devio.read(3,4000)
print(unswer)
devio.close(3)
```

Подключаюсь к терминалу на ПК - вижу корректное входящее сообщение, модуль переходит в режим чтения, я через терминал отправляю данные, но по прошествии таймаута (4000 мс) `unswer = nil`. Данные из терминала точно выходят корректные - проверял другим устройством.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне получить ответ на мое послание?

Comment: 4000 в коде -- это таймаут или количество ожидаемых байт?